# Поэтапная валидация поля

Tags: flutter, dart

Есть вот такой класс, который планируется использовать при валидации различных полей:

```
class InputValidator {
  InputValidator({this.error = ''});
  final String error;

  String email(value) {
    final globalValidator = GlobalValidator();
    bool result = globalValidator.email(value);
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This is not email";
    return result ? null : err;
  }

  String require(value) {
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This field is required";
    return value != '' ? null : err;
  }

  String stepByStep(value) {
    return 'xxx';
  }
}
```

Пример использования

```
Input(
      label: "Email",
      type: 'email',
      controller: emailController,
      validator: inputValidator.stepByStep
      ),
```

Столкнулся с вопросом поэтапной валидации поля. Имеется ввиду, несколько различных валидаций одного поля с разными ошибками. Например, сначала определяю на `require`, а потом на соответствие паттерну email'a.
Планировал создать в этом же классе метод stepByStep, в в котором бы и происходила необходимая магия. Но вот как это правильно сделать в Dart - не знаю.

На JS я бы сделал это условно так:

```
function stepByStep(value, steps){
  stepsName.forEach(stepName => {
    this[stepName](value);
  })
}

stepByStep('xxx', ['require', 'email']);
```

Comment: А как поле должно определить что произошла смена с `require` на `email`? На каком основании?

Comment: @MiT, предполагается, что при иницилизации класса, я передам названия  этапов, а при валидации этапы отработают в нужном порядке (в цикле). Я дополнил вопрос примерным решением на JS. Проблему можно свести к следующему: как вызвать метод класса, имея лишь его название, строкой.  Примерно так: `this['email']()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу только такое решение (Если не хотите использовать `enum`, то можно сделать также на строках):

```
enum InputSteps { require, email }

class InputValidator {
  InputValidator({this.error = ''});
  final String error;

  String _email(value) {
    final globalValidator = GlobalValidator();
    bool result = globalValidator.email(value);
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This is not email";
    return result ? null : err;
  }

  String _require(value) {
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This field is required";
    return value != '' ? null : err;
  }

  String stepByStep(value, InputSteps steps) {
    switch (steps) {
      case InputSteps.require:
        return _email(value);
      case InputSteps.email:
        return _require(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за вариант, но я сделал по-своему). Меня больше привлекает использование цикла)

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
class InputValidator {
  InputValidator({this.error = '', this.steps});
  final String error;
  final List<Function> steps;

  String email(value) {
    final globalValidator = GlobalValidator();
    bool result = globalValidator.email(value);
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This is not email";
    return result ? null : err;
  }

  String require(value) {
    String err = error != '' ? error : "This field is required";
    return value != '' ? null : err;
  }

  String stepByStep(value) {
    for (var element in steps) {
      final check = element(value);
      // здесь провести необходимые действия при том или ином результате последовательной валидации
    }
    return 'xxx';
  }
}
```

Использование:

```
final inputValidator = InputValidator(steps: [InputValidator().require, InputValidator().email]);

Input(
      label: "Email",
      type: 'email',
      controller: emailController,
      validator: inputValidator.stepByStep
      ),
```

Comment: Вариант интересный, но насколько хорошо иметь список с функциями?) +функции `require` и `email` сделайте статичными)

Comment: @MiT, статическими их сделать не получается, т.к. используются внешние переменные. А на счет списка функций: вроде бы норм. Получилось, очень даже удобно, как мне, пока, кажется)